# Toggling between two divs with cookies using jQuery

Tags: jquery, cookies, toggle

I have a function for toggling between two divs (`.grid` and `.list`) with a button (`#button`).

HTML:

```
<a href="#" id="button">Change view</a>
<div class="grid">GRID</div>
<div class="list">LIST</div>
```

jQuery:

```
$('.list').hide();
$('.grid').show();
$('#button').toggle(function() {
    $('.grid').hide();
    $('.list').show();
    return false;
}, function() {
    $('.list').hide();
    $('.grid').show();
    return false;
});
```

How can I add cookies support, so that the toggle state is saved and displayed accordingly after page load? When the user loads the page for the first time .grid view shall be displayed.

I have tried many options from the previous threads, but all of them failed.

Comment: A lot of variants, but removed them all. No use in posting code snippets that do not work.

Comment: thumbs up for your `toggle();` usage.

Comment: is my `toggle();` wrong?

Comment: i think you could do something easier with the toggle! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just set and get the value of a cookie and toggle the elements accordingly (fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/bpcJd/1/):

```
function setCookie(name, value, lifetime_days) {
    var exp = new Date();
    exp.setDate(new Date().getDate() + lifetime_days);
    document.cookie = name + '=' + value + ';expires=' + exp.toUTCString() + ';path=/';
}

function getCookie(name) {
    if(document.cookie) {
        var regex = new RegExp(escape(name) + '=([^;]*)', 'gm'),
        matches = regex.exec(document.cookie);
        if(matches) {
            return matches[1];
        }
    }
}

// show list if cookie exists
if(getCookie('showlist')) {
    $('.list').show();
    $('.grid').hide();
} else {
    $('.list').hide();
    $('.grid').show();
}   

// click handler to toggle elements and handle cookie
$('#button').click(function() {
    // check the current state
    if($('.list').is(':hidden')) {
        // set cookie
        setCookie('showlist', '1', 365);
    } else {
        // delete cookie
        setCookie('showlist', '', -1);
    }
    // toggle
    $('.list').toggle();
    $('.grid').toggle();
    return false;
});
```

Comment: I'm trying out your solution, but it seems to work on the same page. I would like to apply the cookie to the whole site. How can i do it? Or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: It should work throughout the entire domain because `path` is set to `/`

Comment: didn't you forget `;` before `path=`?

Answer (score 1):

If you use jQuery [`$.cookie`](https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie), something like this would work:

```
var $layouts = $('.list, .grid'), // cache objects
    $button = $('#button');       // to avoid overhead

$button.click(function(e, className){
    e.preventDefault();
    if(typeof className != 'undefined')
        $('.'+className).hide();
    $layouts.toggle();

    // set cookie to hold the state
    $.cookie('shown_type', ($layouts.eq(0).is(':visible') ? 'list' : 'grid'));
});

// check to see if a cookie exists for the app state
var shown_type = $.cookie('shown_type');
if(shown_type == 'list' || shown_type == 'grid'){
    $button.trigger('click', [shown_type]); // yes, a cookie exist, show this layout
} else{
    $button.trigger('click', ['list']); // no, a cookie does not exist, show list by default
}
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/Shef/GFj6D/). To test if it works click the switch once to set it to grid, then copy the URL and open a new tab, grid should be the shown layout.

Answer (score 0):

If you use jquery [cookie plugin](https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie) you could do:

```
var visible = false;
if ($.cookie('grid') === 'true'){
    visible = true;
}
$('.list').toggle(!visible);
$('.grid').toggle(visible);


$('#button').click(function(){

    $.cookie('grid', $('.grid').is(':visible') , {expires: 365});
    $('.grid').toggle();
    $('.list').toggle();
});
```

fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/aXCSq/

This display List the first time and then saves the visibility of `".grid"` in a cookie